# application which can pop up like gtalk when some one accesses my server

Tags: monitoring, ubuntu-10.04, network-monitoring

Hi all I am not sure as what should I be looking on Google hence asking here.I have a Ubuntu server with Public IP on which I have a few websites and SSH accounts.I want to know if there is any application/daemon which I can install so that when ever some one does an SSH connection to my server I get a pop up on my laptop that is like gtalk messages which just gives me  some one pop up with a message that user so and so loged in to server.Or some other application which can also tell me when ever http requests are made to my server so that I can be aware or if some one tries a DOS (in this case requests might be difficult to detect) but I get a pop up which says that so and so services is trying to access your server from outside.Other than checking log files is there any way for these things which I asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zenity? xmessage? These are scriptable dialog generators (zenity uses GTK, xmessage should work anywhere) - have a look at fail2ban for log parsing code.